# How to combine many text files into groups of 4

Tags: c#, while-loop, text-files, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a long list of text files (about 80 - 100 files) per folder. I have to combine every 4 text files into a single text file. Each text file is a separate SQL Insert command, so the first line from the first of the 4 text files has to be kept  (INSERT INTO database ( value1, value2, value3 ) VALUES) in the output file, the rest 3 files should skip the first line and just have the values.

The problem I am having is that when combining the last of the 4 files, the last file only copies about half of the last file into the new combined file.

Even if I try to combine only 3 files or 2 files into one. It still only copies about half of the last file.

Here is my code.

`fourCount` indicates when the 4th text file has been combined.

```
        string[] array2 = sqlInsertList.ToArray();
        StreamWriter outfile3 = new StreamWriter(folderPath.Text + "\\" + count + ".txt");
        count++;

        foreach (string dirFileName in array2)
        {
            StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(dirFileName);
            string readFromFile = readFile.ReadLine();

            if(fourCount == 1)
            {
                outfile3 = new StreamWriter(folderPath.Text + "\\" + count + ".txt");
                outfile3.WriteLine(readFromFile);
            }


            while(!readFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                readFromFile = readFile.ReadLine();
                outfile3.WriteLine(readFromFile);
            }

            count++;
            if(fourCount == 4)
            {
                outfile3.WriteLine(";");
                fourCount = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fourCount++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not Closing and therefore not Flushing the output file.

Change it to:

```
 using(StreamWriter outfile3 = new StreamWriter(...))
 {
    count++;

    foreach (string dirFileName in array2)
    {

        if(fourCount == 1)
        {
            outfile3.Close();  // add this
            outfile3 = new StreamWriter(folderPath.Text + "\\" + count + ".txt");
            outfile3.WriteLine(readFromFile);
        }

       ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set **auto Flush** to true property or use **Flush** method ,
However it's no good to leave the stream opened so if possible close it when you know you will not need it